# Execute methods on application startup on web side

Tags: c#, silverlight

Greetings,

I'm in need of a way where I can execute methods on the server side on application startup.
So basicly I'm looking for a server side because of the app.xaml.

Is there any way to accomplish this either via services or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do a request to the web server hosting your Silverlight application when that application starts, right?

You should be able to do this in two ways:

- Either do a web request to the web server. You may have to wait until the Silverlight application has loaded properly before you can do this.
- Or you could use the [HTML Bridge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) functions to call javascript in your containing page from your silverlight application when it starts.

There may be another approach. Instead of doing a request to the server from your Silverlight application, you could possibly do the request in javascript when loading the application. Either by running a script when the hosting page is loaded or running a script before the Silverlight container is loaded.

Comment: Any chance for a sample using a web request?

Comment: The documentation at MSDN is quite comprehensive :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Comment: But what you would like to do is to create a new page on your server that handles the request. The web request would then call that page. Something like the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you! I'll check this out and get back at you either to accept answer or ask more :P

Comment: Good luck! I am not sure if doing web requests while the application is starting is allowed, but you will quickly find out that.

Comment: Havn't been able to try this out yet.
Currently i'm solving my problem by having a custom method in my domain class service and calling that in the app.xaml startup event. But this didn't get me what I wanted to achieve so i'm waiting for a response from the owner wether i'm doing something wrong or if this actually isn't working :P